# Scanning and repairing drive stuck

Tags: boot

So I left my computer on last night and when I came back this morning, it was sitting at the Scanning and repairing drive screen, stuck at 50%. I reset the computer thinking that it wouldn't matter because every other time I've done this in the past it didn't make a difference. However this time I was unable to access the drive that it was scanning which is my old hard drive which has Windows 10 installed but I'm booting from the new solid-state drive (also Windows 10). So since I couldn't access it I rebooted again to try and let the scanning and repair go however it got stuck again but this time at 49%.

Update: the disk scan and repair finished apparently while I was away from my computer, and has booted into Windows, however now the other drive simply says "local disk (F:)" with the subtext NTFS, and in properties it says 0 capacity and used space. Any clues?

Comment: scanning with what? chkdsk? what is the SMART status of the disk?

Comment: @FrankThomas maybe it's chkdsk? I'm not sure since I didn't tell it to do it. It's from boot through that it's happening. I'm not sure how to check the SMART status either.

Comment: I checked the SMART status, and it says good for both drives, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the drive may be damaged. SSDs are harder in my experience to repair and recover than HDDs. My suggestion is to get an external harddrive and [an ubuntu live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD). 
Boot from the live CD, save off everything important you can get access to from the SSD to the external, and RMA the drive.